# Renaming file in scripts

Tags: shell-script

I want to rename `IGNORE_NAMES_20140606-2014-06-06.txt` file to `IGNORE_NAMES_20140606.txt`.

I don't want to use the command below as I want to do it through a shell script.

```
cp -p IGNORE_NAMES_20140606-2014-06-06.txt IGNORE_NAMES_20140606.txt
```

Comment: And why not put that command into your shell script? What's wrong with it? Will you want to do this for many similar files?

Comment: i want to do it for many files hose are result of my search sript. command mentioned is used manually i want to sckip out some part of file name through script.

Comment: Please give a clearer example then. What is your workflow? Will you always want to remove the part of the file name after the first `-`? You need to tell us something about your files in order for us to help you.

Comment: I second @terdon. My own answer `mv`'s only one file because - as I understood it - you were asking for one. If you try to apply it to many the results could be the opposite of useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
f=IGNORE_NAMES_20140606-2014-06-06.txt
mv "$f" "${f%%-*}.txt"
```